# Checking the equality of lists of Comparable objects in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm writing a test using the Spock framework and I found a strange bavior when testing equality of lists.

When I compare two lists like

```
sourceList == targetList
```

and those lists contains Comparable objects of the same type, those objects are tested for equality using its compareTo methods instead of equals.

Is there any simple way how to force Groovy to use equals when testing equality on such lists?

Here is a simple test specification where the test should fail, but it does not.

```
class Test extends Specification {

def "list test"() {
    when:
        def listA = [[index: 1, text: "1"] as Bean, [index: 2, text: "2"] as Bean]
        def listB = [[index: 1, text: "1"] as Bean, [index: 2, text: "3"] as Bean]

    then:
        listA == listB
}

class Bean implements Comparable<Bean> {

    int index
    String text

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Bean o) {
        return index.compareTo(o.index);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + index;
        result = prime * result + ((text == null) ? 0 : text.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Bean)) {
            return false;
        }
        Bean other = (Bean) obj;
        if (index != other.index) {
            return false;
        }
        if (text == null) {
            if (other.text != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!text.equals(other.text)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible sample?

Comment: @Rao see the edited question

Comment: Thank you for the edit, are you using java or groovy?

Answer (score 0):

Asking for a *simple* method is subjective. The key to this answer is that, in Groovy, the `is()` method will [check object equality](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ca/2009/09/groovy-goodness-check-for-object.html).

Consider this new method on `ArrayList`. If appropriate, it will zip together the two lists and call `is()` on each pair of items.

```
ArrayList.metaClass.myCompare = { listB ->
    def result = false
    def listA = delegate
    if (listB && listA.size() == listB.size()) {
        def zipped = [listA, listB].transpose()
        result = zipped.inject(true){ ok, pair ->
            ok && pair[0].is(pair[1])
        }
    }
    result
}
```

then:

```
def beanA = new Bean(index: 1, text: 'a')
def beanA1 = new Bean(index: 1, text: 'a')
def beanB = new Bean(index: 2, text: 'b')

assert [beanA, beanB].myCompare([beanA, beanB])
assert ! [beanA, beanB].myCompare([beanA1, beanB])
assert ! [beanA, beanB].myCompare([beanA])
assert ! [beanA, beanB].myCompare(null)
assert ! [beanA, beanB].myCompare([])
```

Answer (score 0):

In groovy, "==" is replaced with equals if items are not comparable, or with compareTo if they implement Comparable. I do not know a simple way to force equals, if the collections have no duplicates, you can check the elements of the collection one by one:

```
def collectionsEqual (Collection<?> collection1, Collection<?> collection2) {
     if (collection1.size() != collection2.size()) {
         return false
     }
     for (elem1 in collection1) {
         def founded = false;
         for (elem2 in collection2) {
             if (elem1?.equals (elem2)) {
                 founded = true
             }
         }
         if (!founded) {
            return false
         }
     }
     true
}
```

but, in https://www.baeldung.com/java-compareto we have:

> It is also strongly recommended, though not required, to keep the
> compareTo implementation consistent with the equals method
> implementation:
>
> x.compareTo(y) == 0 should have the same boolean value as x.equals(y)
> This will ensure that we can safely use objects in sorted sets and
> sorted maps.